# How to use an un exported object from third party package as return type in golang?

Tags: go, reflection, export, influxdb, go-reflect

In my use case I am using influxdb. I am trying to create a global client to influxdb in Golang. But when I return the influxdb client from a function, the client object is not exported in the influxdb package. So I am not able to return this.

Here is my code:

```
package influxclient

import (
    "github.com/influxdata/influxdb/client/v2"
    "log"
    "time"
    //"net/http"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

const (
    INFLUXDB_NAME = "XXXX"
    USERNAME      = "YYYY"
    PASSWORD      = "ZZZZ"
    HOST          = "http://localhost:8086"
)

var (
    c             = getHTTPClient()
)

func test() {
    // Create a new point batch
    bp, _ := client.NewBatchPoints(client.BatchPointsConfig{
        Database:  INFLUXDB_NAME,
        Precision: "s",
    })

    // Create a point and add to batch
    tags := map[string]string{"cpu": "cpu-total"}
    fields := map[string]interface{}{
        "idle":   10.1,
        "system": 53.3,
        "user":   46.6,
    }
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(c))
    pt, _ := client.NewPoint("cpu_usage", tags, fields, time.Now())
    bp.AddPoint(pt)

    // Write the batch
    c.Write(bp)
}

//publish metrics to metrics db
func PublishMetrics(metricName string, tags map[string]string, fields map[string]interface{}, time time.Time) error {
    fmt.Println("type of client c ", reflect.TypeOf(c))
    // Create a new point batch
    bp, err := client.NewBatchPoints(client.BatchPointsConfig{
        Database:  INFLUXDB_NAME,
        Precision: "s",
    })
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    pt, err := client.NewPoint(metricName, tags, fields, time)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    bp.AddPoint(pt)
    // Write the batch
    c.Write(bp)
    return nil
}


func getHTTPClient() *client.client {
    //make http client for metrics db
    c, err := client.NewHTTPClient(client.HTTPConfig{
        Addr:     HOST,
        Username: USERNAME,
        Password: PASSWORD,
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("FATAL :: Error occured in getting influxdb metric client %s ", err.Error())
    }
    return c
}
```

`getHTTPClient()` function is trying to return the client object `*client.client`.
But the client object is not exported in influxdb golang package.
So how can I handle this problem?
Could anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: As per https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/blob/master/client/v2/client.go#L78 , `Client` is an interface type and it is exported. `Client` type is also what's being returned from `NewHTTPClient` (https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/blob/master/client/v2/client.go#L95). Are you looking for some other type?

Comment: So what kind of error do you get here?

Comment: @SalvadorDali - I am getting the following error for the lower case `client`,

`../influxclient/influxclient.go:67: cannot refer to unexported name client.client
../influxclient/influxclient.go:67: undefined: client.client`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `package client // import "github.com/influxdata/influxdb/client/v2"`
has exported `Client interface` so use `client.Client` instead of `*client.client`:

```
package influxclient

import (
    "log"
    "time"

    "github.com/influxdata/influxdb/client/v2"
    //"net/http"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

const (
    INFLUXDB_NAME = "XXXX"
    USERNAME      = "YYYY"
    PASSWORD      = "ZZZZ"
    HOST          = "http://localhost:8086"
)

var c = getHTTPClient()

func test() {
    // Create a new point batch
    bp, _ := client.NewBatchPoints(client.BatchPointsConfig{
        Database:  INFLUXDB_NAME,
        Precision: "s",
    })

    // Create a point and add to batch
    tags := map[string]string{"cpu": "cpu-total"}
    fields := map[string]interface{}{
        "idle":   10.1,
        "system": 53.3,
        "user":   46.6,
    }
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(c))
    pt, _ := client.NewPoint("cpu_usage", tags, fields, time.Now())
    bp.AddPoint(pt)

    // Write the batch
    c.Write(bp)
}

//publish metrics to metrics db
func PublishMetrics(metricName string, tags map[string]string, fields map[string]interface{}, time time.Time) error {
    fmt.Println("type of client c ", reflect.TypeOf(c))
    // Create a new point batch
    bp, err := client.NewBatchPoints(client.BatchPointsConfig{
        Database:  INFLUXDB_NAME,
        Precision: "s",
    })
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    pt, err := client.NewPoint(metricName, tags, fields, time)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    bp.AddPoint(pt)
    // Write the batch
    c.Write(bp)
    return nil
}

func getHTTPClient() client.Client {
    //make http client for metrics db
    c, err := client.NewHTTPClient(client.HTTPConfig{
        Addr:     HOST,
        Username: USERNAME,
        Password: PASSWORD,
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("FATAL :: Error occured in getting influxdb metric client %s ", err.Error())
    }
    return c
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am getting the following error for upper case Client.
`../influxclient/influxclient.go:42: c.Write undefined (type *client.Client is pointer to interface, not interface)
../influxclient/influxclient.go:62: c.Write undefined (type *client.Client is pointer to interface, not interface)
../influxclient/influxclient.go:77: cannot use c (type client.Client) as type *client.Client in return argument:
 *client.Client is pointer to interface, not interface`

Comment: @dany: do not use pointer to client.Client. or just copy my sample code.

Comment: ah got it. It worked. I am not sure again why `reflect.TypeOf(object)` is giving the pointer `*client.Client` even though the type is `client.Client`